# sudo apt update : Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get, apt

Приобрел виртуальную машину на одном из европейских хостнигов, на ней установлена:

```bsh
root@1f68b6ff:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

Проблема следующая:

При попытке обновить пакеты **apt update** я получаю такую ошибку:

```bsh
root@1f68b6ff:~# sudo apt update
sudo: unable to resolve host 1f68b6ff.cus9763.kvm.st-srv.eu: Name or service not known
Hit:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

На форумах почитал что надо изменить в файле **/etc/apt/sources.list** с списком хостов содержащих пакеты имена доменов с **archive** на **old-releases** но это не до конца помогло. Содержание файла:

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно это поможет https://losst.ru/oshibka-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host

Comment: Это решило ошибку `unable to resole host` но ошибка `Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]` по прежнему осталась

Comment: Посмотрите в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` нет ли там ещё файлов с источниками

Comment: @ArchDemon нет, там даже нет такого файла: `.  ..  apt.conf.d  auth.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list.d  .sources.list.swp  trusted.gpg.d`

Comment: `./sources.list.d/`

Comment: @ArchDemon пустая директория

Comment: Да EOL 19.04 уже, только и всего. Вот и удалены пакеты. Обновляйтесь до чего-нибудь актуального.

Comment: @Мелкий ну всмысле обновляйтесь, а если у меня вся инфраструктура на 18 и 19 убунтах мне что надо всё бросить и идти обновляться?

Comment: проблема была решена установкой 18-й убунты

Comment: Ну как бы да, раз вы сами выбрали использовать релиз с коротким временем жизни и пропустили его EOL. Промежуточные релизы к которым относится 19.04 - живут мало и это именно так задумано. А вот, например, 18.04 - это LTS.

Comment: спасибо поставил 18.04, был не прав